# loading webpage without post back using asp.net and ajax not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

To summarize what I'm trying to do, I've created two forms in my website that when the user clicked the next or prev button, it should supposedly transition from one form to the other without post back. But the problem is when I click next, it doesn't do anything. I have already targeted the respective id's and url in my ajax code but its still not working. As of now, I'm using ajax for those non-post backs and my website is built in asp.net. Hope you guys can help me with this one.

Here is the code below for ajax(loader.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    dataType: "aspx",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('An error occured:' + error);
    },
    timeout: 30000,
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('In Ajax complete function');
    }
});
$("#btnNext").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "Pages/CreateNewItems2.aspx",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1").aspx("").append(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Here is the masterpage for my website:

```
  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">

   <script src="../Javascript/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../Javascript/loader.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery.bxslider.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/StyleSheet.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/font-awesome.min.css"/>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="~/Images/rockSign.png"/>

    <style type="text/css">
    .auto-style2 {
        height: 298px;
    }
   </style>

   </head>
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="main_header">
            <div id="callout">
                <h2>&#9742; 111222333</h2>
                <p>Michigan State Kawasaki Iceland</p>
            </div>
            <h1>MUSIC STORE</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <nav id="nav_menu">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">INSTRUMENTS</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/GuitarBrands.aspx" runat="server">ELECTRIC GUITARS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BASS GUITARS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DRUMS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">AMPLIFIERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FEATURED ARTISTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../Images/cog.png" /></a>
                    <ul class="cog_submenu">
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/NewBrands.aspx" runat="server">CREATE NEW BRAND</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">USE EXISTING BRAND</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Pages/OverviewData.aspx" runat="server">DATA OVERVIEW</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
       </ul>
        </nav>



        <div id="content_area">




            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>



        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy;All Rights Reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is the code for the 1st form which has the next button:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageCMS.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NewBrands.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_NewBrands" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <h3>Create New Brand(Step 1 of 2):</h3>
<table cellspacing="15" class="brandsTable">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

            <strong>Brand Type:</strong></td>

        <td style="height: 37px">

            <asp:TextBox ID="brandType" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 160px; height: 37px;">

            <strong>Brand Name:</strong></td>

        <td style="height: 37px">

            <asp:TextBox ID="brandName" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Height="20px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width: 160px">

            <strong>Brand Image:</strong></td>

        <td>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="brandImage" runat="server" Width="300px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="brandFileUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="brandUploadImage" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" OnClick="brandUploadImage_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>




</table>

<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />


 </asp:Content>
```

And for the 2nd form, I will not include the code here since it is not necessary. The name for the 2nd form is CreateNewItems2.aspx which is located in my Pages folder.

Comment: Any indication in you browsers developer tools console or network tab of what's going on? errors? warnings? messages? http status code indicating error?

Comment: Your button Next runs at server which means the id you're using is only valid at server side. Just inspect the button on your Internet browser and you'll see the actual id. Javascript handler is not being attached.

Comment: @JaromandaX - no error messages. Just when clicking the button, nothing happens.

Comment: @derloopkat - How come when i did a smaller scale version of this code for testing, which has a button that runs at server, it worked. When i tried to apply it on my project, it is not working anymore. I'm not sure if maybe i have just referenced something that it doesn't recognize. Still can't figure it out.

Comment: jQuery doesn't know what datatype "aspx" is. From the browser's perspective, an ASPX page is simply HTML.

Comment: @BrunoEarth Because you're using a master page. The page and master page are actually different aspx files, so both can have a control with same id. To prevent resulting html to have duplicate ids, placeholder names are added.

Comment: @derloopkat - oh i see..may i ask how can i do that in actual code? sorry im really a beginner at this.

Comment: @mason - i've already tried changing it to just html but its still not working.

Comment: @BrunoEarth Either you use the id as it appears on the resulting html page or just replace the server side button by a simple html input type button.